# PHP If statement within else

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement

Newish to php and can't seem to find any info on the web on how to do the following. I need to add the following code after the mysql query in the code below but am unsure how to do it:

```
$membership_type = 'full_member';

if ($item_number == 150) { mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (membership_type) VALUES('". mysql_escape_string($membership_type) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());}
```

Need to add it into here beneath the mysql query.

```
    if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

$sender_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$customerid = $_POST['custom'];

$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];





mysql_query("INSERT INTO paypal (sender_email, customerid, item_name, item_number, payment_status, payment_amount, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email) VALUES('". mysql_escape_string($sender_email) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($customerid) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($item_name) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($item_number) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($payment_status) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($payment_amount) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($payment_currency) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($txn_id) ."', '". mysql_escape_string($receiver_email) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());


}
```

Let me know if I have made any sense. Look forward to your responses.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: Whats the problem? You said it yourself: Add it after `mysql_query()`.

Comment: If possible, try to slim down your example (for example, keep `$sender_email` and remove the rest of the variables). Also, try to indent the code (Fastest way to get it into a stackoverflow question: Mark code, press Ctrl+K). And I'm sorry to say that I fail to understand your problem. Why can't you just add the first lines beneath `mysql_query` in the second code excerpt?

Comment: Whats the problem ? syntax error? query not getting executed? What r uexpecting from the code. Moreover, there  are 2 open brackets in the else but no closing? What you want from the 2 insert queries.

Comment: Have you tried it out? you should try it first. If you face any problem then ask others.

Answer (score -3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php
use this tool.

so after your query put:

```
$membership_type = 'full_member';
if ($item_number == 150) { mysql_query("UPDATE members SET membership_type ='". mysql_escape_string($membership_type) ."' WHERE ID =".mysql_insert_id()) or die(mysql_error());}
```